# SQL Server Database is not getting attached again

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I tried to detach my SQL Server 2008 R2 database for creating a duplicate of it, meanwhile connections to that database were active from Visual Studio (2010). So SQL Server denied to detach. After closing Visual Studio, I tried again and my database was successfully detached.

After detaching my database I tried to copy both files (`.mdf` and `.ldf`) to another folder as a duplicate copy, but I could not do so because I was getting error that says

> You require permission from the computer administrator to make changes to this file

I am using Windows 7 and my account is Administrator. I also tried to attach my database again to SQL Server (running it with administrator permission) but I got the following error:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> Additional Information:
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-Sql statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5 (Access is denied,) while attempting to open or create the phyical file'C:/Mywor/MyDataBase.mdf'.
>
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

Please help me if someone know how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are couple things you can try:

- Stop SQL Server service and see if you can copy files (to stop SQL service go to SQL Server Configuration manager)
- Try to copy some other database files in that directory and see if that works (make sure permissions for both files are exactly the same)
- Try to copy .mdf and .ldf files in original SQL Server data directory (you can find it in SSMS -> Instance properties ->Database Settings
- If you’re not using windows explorer for copying files make sure you run it as admin (right click -> Run as administrator)

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue on the database files directory, or the files themselves.  Just because you're logged on as an administrator doesn't mean that Windows 7 allows you to do anything you want without whinging at you first.  Also, the SQL Server service account may not have the appropriate permissions on the file/folder.

Comment: I am using the same account on which i detached my db. Dont know what options/setting changes are required to fix this.

Comment: First you need to find out what account SQL Server is using (Control Panel\Administrative Tools\Services - It is usually LocalSystem).  Then You need to right-click on the 'C:/Mywor' folder, select Permissions, click the Security tab, and edit the permissions as necessary so that the SQL Server account (SYSTEM if SQL is logging on as LocalSystem) and your account has at least "Modify" permission.

Comment: still the same problem. i am feared it might be corrupted